# Unbalanced Wheatstone bridge with a capacitor in the middle

Tags: capacitor, homework, wheatstone-bridge

I have to find the amount of charge stored in a capacitor after a significant amount of time when $$ R_{1}=1 k \Omega, R_{2}=8 k \Omega, R_{3}=4 k \Omega, R_{4}=2 k \Omega,C=1\mu F,V=10V$$ There is no charge stored in the capacitor.

[image]

I found that this circuit is unbalanced

$$\frac{R_{1}}{R_{4}}\neq\frac{R_{2}}{R_{3}}$$

which means that at least initially there's current flowing through the capacitor. However, I'm having trouble figuring out what's the voltage across the capacitor. There is no angular frequency given, so I can't get the reactance, which means I can't get the total resistance.

I did a quick simulation and found out that the voltage drop across the capacitor is 6V. Am I missing something obvious?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hint: At steady state \$I_C=?\$

Comment: I guess it's zero.

Comment: The terrible (and good) thing about electronics is that guessing isn't a very successful approach. Given a `long time` the capacitor is effectively an "open circuit." So, just mentally remove it. Then you just have two resistor dividers. From their node voltages you can work out the capacitor voltage difference. And from that, the charge on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a question about DC, since \$V\$ is constant. The phrase "after a significant amount of  time" should make you think of "DC operating point", or "quiescent state", in which all capacitors have charged to some steady voltage, and all inductors' magnetic fields have settled also. In that state, capacitors are passing no current, and can be removed from the circuit without changing any currents or potentials anywhere, and inductors are passing a steady maximum current, have no voltage across them, and can be replaced with short-circuits (0Ω resistors).

Therefore, your circuit becomes:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwaMBl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

No need to consider reactance of the capacitor, since the question is dealing with DC. The potentials at A and B are:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_A &= V \frac{R_3}{R_1+R_3} = 10\frac{4k}{1k+4k} = 8V \\ \\
V_B &= V \frac{R_4}{R_2+R_4} = 10\frac{2k}{2k+8k} = 2V \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

The capacitor will evetually charge to \$V_A-V_B = 6V\$.

It may help to replace the potential dividers of R1 & R3, and R2 & R4 with their Thevenin equivalents, to see why this is true. The system of source V, R1 and R3 have the Thevenin equivalent in the blue box, and the red box is the equivalent of the system V, R2 and R4:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flQANI.png)</sup>

The bottom circuit is the entire system reduced to a single source, resistance and capacitance, and I hope now it's "obvious" why C will charge to 6V after a "significant amount of time".

Also, given that we can now clearly see the time constant is \$2.4k\Omega \times 1\mu F\$, you even have an idea of what amount of time is "significant" in this case!